# SupportFragmentManager Transaction with custom animation error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-9.0-pie

I have encountered an issue with custom animations on SupportFragmentManager Transaction when switching fragments. The code I'm using was working with the deprecated FragmentManager, but given that it is deprecated in Android P, I'm using the support version.

```
val ft = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
ft.setCustomAnimations(animationIn, animationOut)
ft.hide(mCurrentFragment!!)
ft.show(f)
ft.commit()
mCurrentFragment = f
```

The error is an NPE when a hide custom animation is specified:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.completeShowHideFragment(FragmentManager.java:1725)

I did try setting animationOut to 0 to make it work, but the fragment transition does not look as good.

Update:
These are the animation items:

animationIn

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="together" >
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_cubic" 
        android:propertyName="x"
        android:duration="300"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:valueFrom="-500"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:startOffset="300" />

    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:duration="300"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:valueFrom="0.3"
        android:valueTo="1"
        android:startOffset="300" />
</set>
```

animationOut

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="together" >
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:duration="300"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:valueFrom="1"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:startOffset="0"/>
</set>
```

Has anyone encountered this issue? 
Thanks.

This is the part of the FragmentManagerImpl class that the error occurs:

```
void completeShowHideFragment(final Fragment fragment) {
    if(fragment.mView != null) {
        FragmentManagerImpl.AnimationOrAnimator anim = this.loadAnimation(fragment, fragment.getNextTransition(), !fragment.mHidden, fragment.getNextTransitionStyle());
        if(anim != null && anim.animator != null) {
            anim.animator.setTarget(fragment.mView);
            if(fragment.mHidden) {
                if(fragment.isHideReplaced()) {
                    fragment.setHideReplaced(false);
                } else {
                    final ViewGroup container = fragment.mContainer;
                    final View animatingView = fragment.mView;
                    // --- the NPE error occurs here
                    container.startViewTransition(animatingView);
                    anim.animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            container.endViewTransition(animatingView);
                            animation.removeListener(this);
                            if(fragment.mView != null) {
                                fragment.mView.setVisibility(8);
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                fragment.mView.setVisibility(0);
            }

            setHWLayerAnimListenerIfAlpha(fragment.mView, anim);
            anim.animator.start();
        } else {
            if(anim != null) {
                setHWLayerAnimListenerIfAlpha(fragment.mView, anim);
                fragment.mView.startAnimation(anim.animation);
                anim.animation.start();
            }

            int visibility = fragment.mHidden && !fragment.isHideReplaced()?8:0;
            fragment.mView.setVisibility(visibility);
            if(fragment.isHideReplaced()) {
                fragment.setHideReplaced(false);
            }
        }
    }

    if(fragment.mAdded && fragment.mHasMenu && fragment.mMenuVisible) {
        this.mNeedMenuInvalidate = true;
    }

    fragment.mHiddenChanged = false;
    fragment.onHiddenChanged(fragment.mHidden);
}
```

Comment: Add something about the animations (animationIn and animationOut), and describe better your problem, we can't help you with such a few informations like in your question

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've added the animations and the code that the error occurs in. Is this somehow a usage issue?